# Two sortable items dragged if trying to move just one card from the sortable group

Tags: polymer-2.x, sortablejs

I have implemented sortablejs in Polymer2.0 element. I am able to drag and drop the item from group. The issue I am facing now is that randomly, not sure why and how, but 2 cards or items gets moved in a group list. Here's the screenshots.

todos is an object which contains group of lists which have array of items.

List
https://www.dropbox.com/s/9wp6vv668p3ckr2/Screenshot%202019-04-30%2007.18.16.png?dl=0

End state when dropped (you see 2 cards moved to the new column which I don't want. I only wanted one card to move)
https://www.dropbox.com/s/int4uyyl3945tjv/Screenshot%202019-04-30%2007.18.50.png?dl=0

Code: Polymer element html

```
 <div class="board­__sprint">
         <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{todos}}" as="row" restamp>
           <div class="list">
             <div class="list­-content">
               <div style="float: left; width: 100%; text-align: center;">
                 <div style="float: left; width: 80%; text-align: left; padding-top: 10px;">
                   <h7 style="color: black; font-size: 20px; font-weight: 800; padding-left: 10px;margin-top: 5px;">
                  [[row.tasks.length]]
                </h7>
                <h7 style="color: black; font-size: 12px; font-weight: 200; padding: 2px; margin-top: 5px;">
                  [[row.title]]
                </h7>
              </div>
              <div style="float: left; width: 20%; text-align: center;">
                <paper-icon-button icon="icons:delete-sweep" style="color: grey;" id="deleteNote" row="[[row]]"
                  on-tap="_removeColumnTriggerDialog"></paper-icon-button>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div style="display: table;">
              <div style="width: 90%; height: 3px; background: #0c66b5;">
                <h7>&nbsp;</h7>
              </div>
              <div id="myid[[row.id]]" class="list-group" style="min-height: 120px;">
                <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{row.tasks}}" as="todo" restamp>
                  <!-- <div class$="{{determineDragable(todo)}}"> -->
                  <div class="item">
                    <div class="ticket" data-index$="{{todo.id}}">
                      <paper-card style="float:center; width: 100%;" class="singleColor" data-index$="{{todo}}"
                        data-index$="{{row}}">
                        <div style="float:left; width: 15%" style$="{{getRandomInt(0, 20)}}">
                          <h7>&nbsp;</h7>
                        </div>
                        <div style="width: 100%">
                          <div style="float: left; width: 15%; vertical-align:center">

                            <px-icon icon="px-vis:pin"></px-icon>
                          </div>
                          <div style="float: left; width: 70%">
                            <h7 class="banksTitle" style="color: black; font-size: 12px; text-align:left;">
                              <b>[{{index}}]</b> &nbsp; &nbsp; [[todo.actTitle]]
                            </h7>
                            <h7 class="banksTitle" style="color: grey; font-size: 12px; text-align:left;">
                              [[todo.actDesc]]
                            </h7>
                          </div>
                          <template is="dom-if" if="{{checkDummy(todo)}}">
                            <div style="float: left; width: 15%;">
                              <paper-icon-button icon="icons:close" style="color: grey;" id$="bt_readmore"
                                todo="[[todo]]" row="[[row]]" on-tap="_moveDel"></paper-icon-button>
                            </div>
                          </template>
                          <template is="dom-if" if="{{checkDummyNot(todo)}}">
                            <div style="float: left; width: 15%;">
                              <paper-icon-button icon="image:crop-square" style="color: grey;" id$="bt_readmore"
                                todo="[[todo]]" row="[[row]]" on-tap=""></paper-icon-button>
                            </div>
                          </template>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                          <h5>&nbsp;</h5>
                        </div>
                        <div style="width: 100%;display: table;">
                          <div style="float: left; width: 15%;">

                            &nbsp;
                          </div>
                          <div style="float: left; width: 70%; text-align: center;">
                            <template is="dom-if" if="{{checkDummy(todo)}}">
                              <paper-icon-button icon="av:playlist-add-check" style="color: green;"
                                id$="bt_readmore" todo="[[todo]]" row="[[row]]" on-tap=""></paper-icon-button>
                            </template>
                            <template is="dom-if" if="{{checkDummy(todo)}}">
                              <paper-icon-button icon="editor:attach-file" style="color: maroon;" id$="bt_readmore"
                                todo="[[todo]]" row="[[row]]" on-tap=""></paper-icon-button>
                            </template>
                            <template is="dom-if" if="{{checkDummy(todo)}}">
                              <paper-icon-button icon="editor:border-color" style="color: grey;" id$="bt_readmore"
                                todo="[[todo]]" row="[[row]]" on-tap=""></paper-icon-button>
                            </template>
                          </div>
                          <div style="float: right; width: 15%;">

                            &nbsp;
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </paper-card>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </template>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div>
              <h5>&nbsp;</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="addTicket">
              <paper-button raised class="blue" on-tap="_addTicketDialog" row={{row}}>Add Ticket</paper-button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </template>
    </div>
```

and the JS script specific to onAdd event of sortablejs

```
_todosChanged() {
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('this.todos.length = ' + this.todos.length);
        var self = this;
        if (this.todos !== null || this.todos !== undefined) {
        var lowestOrder = 0;
        var highestOrder = 0;
        var options = {
          group: 'shared',
          animation: 200,
          sort: false,
          draggable: ".item",
          onAdd: function (evt) {
            console.log('---FROM----');
            console.log(evt.from.id);
            console.log('---TO----');
            console.log(evt.to.id);
            console.log('---ITEM----');
            console.log(evt.item.innerText);
            var foundFrom = false;
            var fromId = evt.from.id.substr('myid'.length);
            var fromCol;
            var foundTo = false;
            var toId = evt.to.id.substr('myid'.length);
            var toCol;
            console.log('fromId =' + fromId + '  toId =' + toId);
            self.todos.forEach(child => { //todos = 1, 3, 4 & row = 3
              if (!foundTo) {
                if (child.id === toId) {
                  foundTo = true;
                  toCol = child;
                }
              }
              if (!foundFrom) {
                if (child.id === fromId) {
                  foundFrom = true;
                  fromCol = child;
                }
              }
            });
            console.log('toCol = ' + JSON.stringify(toCol));
            console.log('fromCol = ' + JSON.stringify(fromCol));
            //find item in from col
            var str = evt.item.innerText;
            var itemKey = str.substr(0, str.indexOf(':'));
            itemKey = itemKey.substr(itemKey.indexOf('KEY-')).substr('KEY-'.length);
            console.log('itemKey = ' + itemKey);
            var arrItemToRemove = fromCol.tasks;
            console.log('arrItemToRemove = ' + JSON.stringify(arrItemToRemove));
            var indexItem = -1;
            for (var i = 0; i < arrItemToRemove.length; i++)
              if (arrItemToRemove[i].id === itemKey) indexItem = i;
            console.log('indexItem = ' + indexItem);
            if (indexItem < 0 || indexItem > arrItemToRemove.length) {
              document.getElementById('toastError').show('No item found');
            } else {
              // console.log('indexItem=' + indexItem);
              var newItemToPush = arrItemToRemove[indexItem];
              console.log('newItemToPush=' + JSON.stringify(newItemToPush));
              //now add the item to the right
              var arr = toCol.tasks;
              if (arr === null || arr === undefined) arr = [];
              arr.push({
                'actTitle': newItemToPush.actTitle,
                'actDesc': newItemToPush.actDesc,
                'actDt': newItemToPush.actDt,
                'parent': toCol.order,
                'id': newItemToPush.id
              });
              console.log('arr=' + JSON.stringify(arr));
              self.$.query.ref.child(toCol.$key).child('tasks').set(arr);
              var nwArr = arrItemToRemove.splice(indexItem, 1);
              document.getElementById('toastShort').show('Data moved: ' + newItemToPush.actTitle);
              self.$.query.ref.child(fromCol.$key).child('tasks').set(arrItemToRemove);
            }
          },
        };
        this.todos.forEach(child => {
          if (lowestOrder > child.order) lowestOrder = child.order;
          if (highestOrder < child.order) highestOrder = child.order;
          // console.log(child.id);
          var selector = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('#myid' + child.id);
          Sortable.create(selector, options);
        });
        console.log('lowestOrder=' + lowestOrder + ' highestOrder=' + highestOrder);
        this.set('order', highestOrder);
      }
    });

  }
```

Comment: Hi, on detail debugging this is what I found. 1st and last element in any column is not an issue. The behaviour only happens for middle cards in the column list. Another observation is if I don't update the todos list in the javascript i.e. remove element from "from" column (adding to the "to" column is not an issue. tested it) then this issue is observed.

Comment: I see the issue is with todos list item being removed. This removal of item leads to 2 cards being moved in sortables. If I comment this line in the code then sortablejs works fine for all elements in the list i.e. first, last and middle ones too .... //self.$.query.ref.child(fromCol.$key).child('tasks').set(arrItemToRemove);

Comment: I guess the issue is with sortablejs when an element is removed from the list. somehow dom-repeat and sortablejs works differently. I used restamp option in both the dom-repeats but that too didn't solved the issue.

Comment: Help .. please as this is not what I wish to go in prod

Comment: Create a minimal reproduction of this in JSBin so I can have a look

Comment: Hi Owen, here is the codepen . ... https://codepen.io/vinayak-vanarse/pen/zXQaZj?editors=1111       I couldn't simulate firebase realtime database which is todos list. But tried to set the todos list in local object of the element to show that removing items from todos list actually causes different behaviour.

Comment: I am not entirely sure as to the issue specifically, but I do not believe it is an issue with Sortable. The one thing that might be causing it is if you are calling `Sortable.create()` multiple times on the same element. I see it is done in `_todosChanged()`. Initializing Sortable multiple times on the same element will cause problems, I would recommend only initializing it at the start and see if that solves the issue for you.

Comment: It could be that. Let me try to get it initialised in ready() method of polymer which would do it only once.

Comment: Nope. I think issue with Sortablejs on item remove from the list. I added a boolean variable in element so that only once Sortable.create() is executed. so whenever the todos list is changed it checks the flag for firstTimeRender and if set to true (on first time) it skips the .create() code. Still same issue. Something to do with removing items from todos.

Comment: This is killing me now. I see randomly (but most often) middle cards gets moved along with the one immediate next to the next column. And the behaviour is only observed when I change todos list i.e. add / remove moved elements. What I plan to do is update todos list in firebase database when the user exists the page. It is not an ideal solution but it will resolve the issue. Any alternative solution that you guys see will be best suited in this case?

Comment: I am sorry but this code has much too much going on for me to be able to test it. My time is very limited. If that is the most minimal reproduction you can make, then it is one of those problems that only it's creator can solve. If you can make the example as bare-bones as possible, that shows SortableJS giving this issue without any unnecessary code, then I can isolate the issue. But you have a framework and a custom event in your demo and I am inclined to believe it is the cause of the issue. With this I cannot help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok ... this is what I did to resolve the issue

1. firebase query is async so I used observer function to update the dummy variable which is used in dom-template. I used async to do that.
2. The real issue was when you remove element from list that sortablejs has used to render the items. By use of Dummy variable that is copy of firebase object I was able to avoid this issue.
3. I offline sync the object when user leaves the page. It works fine now.